# Replace text + wildcard number in string in class

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have a piece of server-generated html (i can't directly edit the html so modifications have to be javascript/jquery) & I need to strip one bit of text + a variable number but leave everything else. Here's my html:

```
<td>
    <font class="carttext">
        [Specifications:30][Specifications:
        <br> These are other specifications: here & here
        <br>And even more: because life is hard]
    </font>
</td>
```

Note that the `[Specifications:30]` could be `[Specifications:40]` or `[Specifications:90]` or `[Specifications:120]` etc. but will always start with `[Specifications:` and end with the variable number & `]`

And here's my non-working-but-best-effort jquery:

```
var cartText = $(document.getElementsByClassName("carttext"));

cartText.html(function (index, html) {
    return html.replace("[Specifications:" + /[0-9]+\]/, '');
});
```

also tried :

```
var cartText = $(document.getElementsByClassName("carttext"));

cartText.html(function (index, html) {
    return html.replace("[Specifications:" + /d +\]/, '');
});
```

I have more than one occurrence of `"[Specifications:"` in the `carttext` class, so I'm only trying to strip the occurrence where the string is `"[Specificaitons:(variable number here)"`

UPDATE: I'm trying to strip not just the number, but the `[Specifications:` also, so that:

```
   <font class="carttext">
   [Specifications:30][Specifications: <br> These are other
   specifications: here & here <br>And even more: because life is hard]
   </font>
```

becomes

```
   <font class="carttext">
    [Specifications:<br> These are other specifications: here & here
    <br>And even more: because life is hard]
   </font>
```

Sorry for not specifying previously

Comment: `html.replace(/\[Specifications:\s*\d+\]/g, '');`. The `g` is a global flag--that allows the regex to match the string multiple times.

Comment: You can not combine a string and a regular expression. That is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The regex should be delimited by `/`
2. `[` is special symbol in regex, so it need to be escaped by preceding with /
3. Use `g`-global flag to replace **all** occurrences

As jQuery is loaded on the page, use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) as follow.

```js
$('.carttext').html(function(i, oldHtml) {
  return oldHtml.replace(/\[Specifications:\d+\]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<font class="carttext">
  [Specifications:30][Specifications:
  <br /> These are other specifications: here & here
  <br />And even more: because life is hard]
</font>
```

Comment: Works great on desktop, but doesn't seem to work on mobile. Is there something else I need to add to make it compatible with mobile?

Comment: @KateTheGreat Should work on mobile too. I don't see anything in the code that isn't supported by mobile browsers. Can you see errors in console using remote debugging.